# how to implement mouseEnter and mouseLeave event in QWidget?

Tags: qt

how to implement mouseEnter and mouseLeave event in QWidget?

if the mouseEnter to the QWidget then i need to set the Background color into Gray,
if the mouseLeave from the QWidget then i need to set the background color is white

i tried

```
void enterEvent(QEvent *);
void leaveEvent(QEvent *);
```

in the inside of the enter&leave event i am using bool varibale set true & false. and i am calling the QPainter event update();

the code below:

```
void Test::enterEvent(QEvent *)
{
   _mouseMove=true;
    update();

}

void Test::leaveEvent(QEvent *)
{
   _mouseMove=false;
    update();

}

void Test::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&m_targetImage);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

        if(_mouseMove){
            painter.fillRect(QRect(0,0,width(),height()),Qt::white);}
        else{
            painter.fillRect(QRect(0,0,width(),height()),Qt::gray);}

    painter.end();

    QPainter p;
    p.begin(this);
    p.drawImage(0, 0, m_targetImage);
    p.end();
}
```

i am getting following error when i am moving the mouse in the QWidget

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

Please help me to fix this. if any one having sample code please provide me....

Comment: You could also listen to the hover events, which do the update() themselves. Qt Style Sheets also allow different settings depending on the hover state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would use a member to save the current background color instead of a boolean. This will simplify the paintEvent code:

```
painter.fillRect(QRect(...), m_backColor);
```

I guess the errors appears for the first QPainter. Why are you using a QPainter to fill the image? If the var is a QImage you can use the [fill function](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qimage.html#fill) by example and the call drawImage as you do. You have the same kind of function for [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qpixmap.html#fill).

Answer (score 6):

QWidgets also support the `underMouse` method which could be used instead of the StyleOption or Attribute solution:

```
if(underMouse()){
    painter.fillRect(QRect(0,0,width(),height()),Qt::white);}
else{
    painter.fillRect(QRect(0,0,width(),height()),Qt::gray);}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [styles](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/stylesheet-reference.html).

Most widget support the `:hover` pseudo state, set the backgroundcolor property for your widget in the style

```
test->setStyleSheet(":hover {background-color: #dddddd;}");
```

or do it through designer, which is even more convenient, if you need to do custom drawing do it. but you don't need to do it for anything that just changes basic widget looks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:
Use QStyleOption.

```
QStyleOption sopt;
sopt.initFrom(this);
if(sopt.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
{
    painter.fillRect(QRect(...), m_colorHover);
}
else
{
    painter.fillRect(QRect(...), m_colorNotHover);
}
```

Don't need use extra variable, like `_mouseMove`